# How to access snowflake query profile overview statistics via SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake SnowSight UI, in the Query Profile view, there is a section called Profile Overview where you can see the breakdown of the total execution time. It contains statistics like Processing, Local Disk I/O, Remote Disk I/O, Synchronization etc.

[image: Profile Overview]

Full list here
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-activity.html#profile-overview

I want to access those statistics programmatically instead of having to navigate to that section for each query that I want to analyze. The only system view I know that provides query statistics is the QUERY_HISTORY however it doesn't contain those stats.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

Question is, can I get those stats in any of the system views? If so, where and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to programmatically access query profile using [GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_query_operator_stats.html)

> Returns statistics about individual query operators within a query. You can run this function for any query that was executed in the past 14 days.
>
> For example, you can use this information to determine which operators are consuming the most resources. As another example, you can use this function to identify joins that have more output rows than input rows, which can be a sign of an “exploding” join (e.g. an unintended Cartesian product).
>
> These statistics are also available in the query profile tab in Snowsight. The `GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS()` function makes the same information available via a programmatic interface.
>
> **The GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS function is a table function. It returns rows with statistics about each query operator in the query**

```
set query_id = '<query_ud>';

select *
from table(get_query_operator_stats($query_id));
```

Comment: Is it possible to get results for more than 1 query in one single run?

Answer (score 2):

### 2023 update: GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS()

- See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74824120/132438 with Lukasz answer.
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_query_operator_stats.html

---

Bad news: There's no programmatic way to get this.

Good news: This is a frequent request, so we might eventually have news.

In the internal tracker I left a note to update this answer once there is progress we can report.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions#get-sfqueryprofile. Doing it at scale (scraping-style) will likely yield ~60%-80% success rate. Please don't abuse it.

Inspired by a clever customer who did that to get what is now offered by https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html

Completely unsupported as it says so on the repo homepage.

Comment: This is great and saves me a lot of time from writing my own scraper until an official API is provided. I have around 3000 queries to analyze and I will put a few seconds between requests so nothing to worry about :)

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, there is an upcoming feature called GET_QUERY_STATS (currently in private preview) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/LIMITEDACCESS/get_query_stats.html that will do just this and obviate the reason for Get-SFQueryProfile once it ships.