# How to interpret the percentage values in the Snowflake query profile overview?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a follow up to my previous question: [How to access snowflake query profile overview statistics via SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804261/how-to-access-snowflake-query-profile-overview-statistics-via-sql)

Here is the profile overview of a query I am analyzing

[image]

Total Execution Time is: 2 seconds (2019 milliseconds to be precise)

In the same section we see a breakdown by CPU, disk usage etc. The percentages add up to 100%. Great.

Anyone looking at these values in the UI would be inclined to assume that the 72.9% which was spent on Processing is 72.9% of the Total Execution Time (2019 milliseconds); in other words 1472 milliseconds is spent on processing.

Now, thanks to the SF Snowsight extension tool recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805083/447807) I am able to see the raw numbers that are used to calculate those percentages. The problem is, the numbers don't add up; they are totally different. Here are the numbers that I got back from the unofficial tool:

```
    "waits" : [ {
      "name" : "Processing",
      "value" : 186.0,
      "percentage" : 0.7294117647058823
    }, {
      "name" : "Local Disk IO",
      "value" : 46.0,
      "percentage" : 0.1803921568627451
    }, {
      "name" : "Synchronization",
      "value" : 19.0,
      "percentage" : 0.07450980392156863
    }, {
      "name" : "Initialization",
      "value" : 4.0,
      "percentage" : 0.01568627450980392
    } ],
    "totalStats" : {
      "name" : "Time spent",
      "value" : 255.0,
      "percentage" : 1.0
    }
```

The percentage values are clearly calculated by dividing the "value" in each of the waits key to the value of the "Time spent" key in the totalStats. E.g Local Disk IO: 46/255 = 18%

The name "Time spent" suggest that this value, 255, is some sort of time unit. It can't be milliseconds because the total time is 2019 milliseconds, which is reported in a few places and can also be calculated by end_time - start_time.

```
...
"description" : "Execution",
"timeInMs" : 2019,
"state" : "success",
...
```

I manually checked multiple queries and the situation is the same every time. The queries are all single step so it is not like I am missing values in other steps.

Questions are:

- How is this "Time spent" value in "totalStats" section of the "global" query statistics calculated?
- Is it really a time unit as the name suggests? If so what is the time unit? If not, what is this value?
- Why are the percentages under the Total Execution Time calculated over this value but not the timeInMs value?

Any comments are appreciated as the results of my analysis will be used for Snowflake performance evaluation and I would like to refrain from making any guesses regarding what these percentages mean.

Comment: total time includes queuing time, and setting up the warehouse time... have you account for these bits?

Comment: the other part might be "given these are not public stats" they might be a "little funky".. and trying to get them to add up might be "makes the unhappy logic"

Comment: I know some of the other "public" stats (a couple (3-4) of years ago) didn't add up at all, like disk usage, the manual stated a - b = c but sum(b) + sum(c) was 10x sum(a)... so whack.

Comment: Both the queuing time and the warehouse provisioning time should be zero (or near zero). Warm up queries were run to prepare the warehouse for testing, so the warehouse was up and running by the time testing began. Test queries were run sequentially with no other queries using the warehouse. I understand that the stats could be "funky" given that they are not documented. What I am essentially trying to understand is how those percentage values under the Total Execution Time should be interpreted.

Comment: Given that the explanation of the percentage vales are documented here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#execution-time, what further information are you looking for?

Comment: @NickW As succinct as I can put it: would it be correct to claim that these percentage values are the breakdown of the Total Execution Time? (Despite looking under the hood, albeit using the unofficial tool provided by Snowflake devs, and seeing that those percentage values are obviously calculated differently?)