# How to get GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS() for multiple queries?

Tags: sql, performance, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The new Snowflake GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS() allows me to get the stats for one query - but how do I get the stats for multiple queries?

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_query_operator_stats.html

([asked by Yaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74824120/132438))

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a SQL script to go through multiple query ids and store the results of `GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS()` in a table.

First, create the table that will store the results:

```sql
create or replace table query_operator_stats_cache
as
select ''::string query_id, * 
from table(get_query_operator_stats(last_query_id()))
-- just for the schema
limit 0;
```

Then you can go over a list of query ids:

```sql
declare
  query_id string;
  c1 cursor for 
    select query_id
    from queries
    where query_id not in (select query_id from query_operator_stats_cache);
begin
  open c1;
  for record in c1 do
    fetch c1 into query_id;
    insert into query_operator_stats_cache
      select :query_id, * from table(get_query_operator_stats(:query_id));  
  end for;
  return query_id;
end;
```

Go deeper on my post:

- https://hoffa.medium.com/deep-performance-analysis-with-the-new-query-operator-stats-in-snowflake-74837971c5d3

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get multiple query profiles at once by generating query for multiple query_ids and executing it:

```
DECLARE 
  query TEXT;
  rs    RESULTSET;
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE($$SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_query_operator_stats('<query_id>'))$$,
                 '<query_id>', t.query_id), ' UNION ALL ') AS query
  INTO query
  FROM TABLE(information_schema.query_history(RESULT_LIMIT=>5)) AS t;

  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

Comment: That's cool! I wonder if it the `UNION` increases the risk of timeout - vs going 1 by 1.